# Copy MemoryStream of a pdf from file to a MemoryStream created from PdfPTable

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, memorystream

I'm trying to create a two page PDF that contains: 1)A 2x2 W2 on one page, this portion is correct; 2)(new)the instructions for the first page, this portion is not working.

Currently this code runs fine, but all I get at save time is the initial PDF of the 2x2 W2. I feel that I am missing some small bit of logic/conversion (due to the table) or the stream might be too large.

Stream Creation:

```
    public Dictionary<string, MemoryStream> CreateW2FromBitmap(List<Employee> info, Employer employerInfo, bool fourPerPage)
    {
        StringFormat rightAlign = new StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.NoClip);
        StringFormat centerAlign = new StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.NoClip);
        PdfPTable imageTable = new PdfPTable(2) { WidthPercentage = 82 };

        imageTable.DefaultCell.Border = iTextSharp.text.Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
        imageTable.DefaultCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
        rightAlign.Alignment = StringAlignment.Far;
        centerAlign.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
        var brushColor = Brushes.Black;
        var W2ImageDictionary = new Dictionary<string, MemoryStream>();
        var font = new System.Drawing.Font("Courier New", 47);
        var document = new Document(PageSize.LETTER, 0, 0, 10, 0);

        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(Bitmap.FromFile(@"\\ProdFS\DocumentArchive$\MessagingService\W2\W2_Images_For_Creation\Copy-2_" + employerInfo.taxYear + ".png"));

        foreach (var property in info)
        {
            MemoryStream tempImageStream = new MemoryStream();

            var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, tempImageStream);
            var employeeCityStateZipCode = CityStateZipDelimiter(property.CityStateZip);
            var employerCityStateZipCode = CityStateZipDelimiter(employerInfo.CityStateZip);

            document.Open();
            writer.CloseStream = false;

            for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
            {
                switch (i)
                {
                    case 1:
                        bmp = new Bitmap(Bitmap.FromFile(@"\\ProdFS\DocumentArchive$\MessagingService\W2\W2_Images_For_Creation\Copy-2_" + employerInfo.taxYear + ".png"));
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        bmp = new Bitmap(Bitmap.FromFile(@"\\ProdFS\DocumentArchive$\MessagingService\W2\W2_Images_For_Creation\Copy-2_" + employerInfo.taxYear + ".png"));
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        bmp = new Bitmap(Bitmap.FromFile(@"\\ProdFS\DocumentArchive$\MessagingService\W2\W2_Images_For_Creation\Copy-B_" + employerInfo.taxYear + ".png"));
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        bmp = new Bitmap(Bitmap.FromFile(@"\\ProdFS\DocumentArchive$\MessagingService\W2\W2_Images_For_Creation\Copy-C_" + employerInfo.taxYear + ".png"));
                        break;
                }

                Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
                g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
                g.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
                g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;

                //left col
                g.DrawString(property.EmployeeSSN, font, brushColor, 765, 90, centerAlign);
                g.DrawString(employerInfo.EIN, font, brushColor, 30, 190);
                g.DrawString(employerInfo.Name, font, brushColor, 30, 322);
                g.DrawString(employerInfo.AddressName, font, brushColor, 30, 392);
                g.DrawString(employerCityStateZipCode.Item1 + ", " + employerCityStateZipCode.Item2 + " " + employerCityStateZipCode.Item3, font, brushColor, 30, 462);
                //g.DrawString(employerInfo.ControlNumber, font, brushColor, 30, 590);
                g.DrawString(property.EmployeeName, font, brushColor, 30, 715);
                g.DrawString(property.AddressName, font, brushColor, 30, 820);
                g.DrawString(employeeCityStateZipCode.Item1 + ", " + employeeCityStateZipCode.Item2 + " " + employeeCityStateZipCode.Item3, font, brushColor, 30, 890);

                //middle col
                g.DrawString(property.GrossWages, font, brushColor, 1765, 190, rightAlign);
                g.DrawString(property.SocialSecurityWages, font, brushColor, 1765, 290, rightAlign);
                g.DrawString(property.MedicareWages, font, brushColor, 1765, 390, rightAlign);
                //g.DrawString(property.SocialSecurityTips, font, brushColor, 1765, 514, rightAlign);
                //g.DrawString(property.verificationcode, font, brushColor, 1765, 626.5, rightAlign);
                //g.DrawString(property.NonqualifiedPlans, font, brushColor, 1765, 750, rightAlign);
                //g.DrawString("X", font, brushColor, 1320, 799);
                g.DrawString(property.RetirementPlan.ToString(), font, brushColor, 1463, 795);
                //g.DrawString("X", font, brushColor, 1620, 799);

                //right col
                g.DrawString(property.FederalTaxWithheld, font, brushColor, 2275, 190, rightAlign);
                g.DrawString(property.SocialSecurityTaxWithheld, font, brushColor, 2275, 290, rightAlign);
                g.DrawString(property.MedicareTaxWithheld, font, brushColor, 2275, 390, rightAlign);
                //g.DrawString(property.AllocatedTips, font, brushColor, 2275, 514, rightAlign);
                //g.DrawString(property.DependentCareBenefits, font, brushColor, 2275, 626, rightAlign);
                g.DrawString(property.TwelveARight, font, brushColor, 2275, 690, rightAlign);
                g.DrawString(property.TwelveALeft, font, brushColor, 1900, 690, rightAlign);
                //g.DrawString(property.TwelveBRight, font, brushColor, 2275, 850, rightAlign);
                //g.DrawString(property.TwelveBLeft, font, brushColor, 1900, 850, rightAlign);
                //g.DrawString(property.TwelveCRight, font, brushColor, 2275, 962, rightAlign);
                //g.DrawString(property.TwelveCLeft, font, brushColor, 1900, 962, rightAlign);
                //g.DrawString(property.TwelveDRight, font, brushColor, 2275, 1074, rightAlign);
                //g.DrawString(property.TwelveDLeft, font, brushColor, 1900, 1074, rightAlign);

                //bottom row
                g.DrawString(employerInfo.State, font, brushColor, 30, 1142);
                g.DrawString(employerInfo.SIN, font, brushColor, 450, 1142, centerAlign);
                g.DrawString(property.StateWages, font, brushColor, 1050, 1142, rightAlign);
                g.DrawString(property.StateIncomeTax, font, brushColor, 1380, 1142, rightAlign);
                //g.DrawString(property.LocalWages, font, brushColor, 1824, 1142);
                //g.DrawString(property.LocalIncomeTax, font, brushColor, 2284, 1142);
                //g.DrawString(property.LocalityName, font, brushColor, 2704, 1142);
                g.Flush();

                if (fourPerPage == true)
                {//four images on one page
                    bmp.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone);

                    try
                    {
                        iTextSharp.text.Image pic = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(bmp, ImageFormat.Bmp);


                        if (pic.Height > pic.Width)
                        {
                            float percentage = 0f;
                            percentage = 400 / pic.Height;
                            pic.ScalePercent(percentage * 100);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            float percentage = 0f;
                            percentage = 240 / pic.Width;
                            pic.ScalePercent(percentage * 100);
                        }
                        pic.Border = iTextSharp.text.Rectangle.BOX;
                        pic.BorderColor = BaseColor.BLACK;
                        pic.BorderWidth = 3f;
                        imageTable.AddCell(pic);

                        g.Dispose();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        throw ex;
                    }
                }
                else
                {//two images per page
                    iTextSharp.text.Image pic = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(bmp, ImageFormat.Bmp);
                    pic.ScalePercent(80);
                    document.Add(pic);
                    g.Dispose();
                }
            }
            document.Add(imageTable);
            //document.NewPage();
            document.Close();

            //attempt to add a bmp
            //document.Add(instructions);
            //attempt to add pdfsharp to it
            //PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfDocument uno = PdfSharp.Pdf.IO.PdfReader.Open(@"\\ProdFS\DocumentArchive$\MessagingService\W2\W2_Images_For_Creation\" + employerInfo.taxYear + "_Form_W2_Instructions.pdf", PdfSharp.Pdf.IO.PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import);
            //document.Add(uno); 
            var InstructionStream = new MemoryStream(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"\\ProdFS\DocumentArchive$\MessagingService\W2\W2_Images_For_Creation\" + employerInfo.taxYear + "_Form_W2_Instructions.pdf"));
            InstructionStream.Position = 0;
            InstructionStream.CopyTo(tempImageStream);

            using (FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(@"\\ProdFS\DocumentArchive$\MessagingService\W2\W2_Images_For_Creation\" + employerInfo.taxYear + "_Form_W2_Instructions.pdf"))
            {
                MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
                memStream.SetLength(fileStream.Length);
                fileStream.Read(memStream.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)fileStream.Length);
                memStream.CopyTo(tempImageStream);
                fileStream.CopyTo(tempImageStream);
                //tempImageStream.CopyTo(memStream);
                //tempImageStream.CopyTo(fileStream);

                memStream.CopyToAsync(tempImageStream);
                fileStream.CopyToAsync(tempImageStream);
                //tempImageStream.CopyToAsync(memStream);
                //tempImageStream.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
            }


            W2ImageDictionary.Add(property.EmployeeID, tempImageStream);
        }

        return W2ImageDictionary;
    }
```

Stream save as PDF:

```
    public void Save(Dictionary<string, MemoryStream> dictionaryOfImages, int year, string path)
    {
        string saveToFolder = path;
        if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(saveToFolder))
        {
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(saveToFolder);
        }

        foreach (var key in dictionaryOfImages.Keys)
        {
            var fileStream = File.Create(saveToFolder + "/" + key + "_" + year + ".pdf");
            dictionaryOfImages[key].Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            dictionaryOfImages[key].CopyTo(fileStream);
            fileStream.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try following :  byte[] buffer = new byte[memStream.Length];
            memStream.Position = 0;
            memStream.Read(buffer, 0, (int)memStream.Length);
            W2ImageDictionary.Add(property.EmployeeID, buffer);

Comment: Is there another way to add the second stream to the first? When I reposition tempImageStream to 0 I get the second page, but if I do/don't the memStream I still only get the First page. So the copy is working, but won't create two pages.

Comment: well I ended up adding an instructionTable that is only one cell and changing the instruction pdf into a png. Then loaded that in after adding a new page. This works, I'm still wondering if it was a conversion issue or something. Thanks for the help though

Comment: You should search for "merging PDFs", e.g. on stack overflow or on the iText developer site. There you'll find out how to correctly merge multiple pdf into one. In particular you cannot simply write multiple pdf into the same stream and expect the result to be a merge of them.

Comment: You can use a List<byte> instead of the array so you can append more data.